# PHP regular expression (including bracket specific and any letter / number / symbol dependant on placement in string)

Tags: php, regex

After a few hours of experimenting with http://www.phpliveregex.com/ - I have become rather stuck. I am looking for a regular expression that would satisfy the following example criteria:

```
arrname = array('blackberry', 'apple', 'orange', 'mandarin');
arrname = array('****11111', '2%%%2', '3$$$$33', '444£££44');
```

So essentially it boils down to the following pattern:

```
[arrname = array('] [any characters] [', '] [any characters] [', '] [any characters] [', '] [any characters] [');]
```

Where **any character is literally any (letter / number / symbol)** - in any order **(but requires a length of at least 1 character)** - hence the need for a regular expression using the `preg_match()` function.

My trouble is making the regular expression match the pattern stated above (repeated below).

```
[arrname = array('] [any characters] [', '] [any characters] [', '] [any characters] [', '] [any characters] [');]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Having tried to implement `preg_match()` I've failed and am obviously missing something really stupid (errors listed below). Any idea's?

First (using double quotes on the expression)

```
$pattern = "arrname = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);";
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);
```

Gives me the error `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Second (using single quote on the expression)

```
$pattern = 'arrname = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);
```

Gives me the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '('`

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3hq

Comment: Show what you've tried. We can't help you understand your error if you don't show what you've written.

Comment: What you've written is practically the regexp. All you have to do is replace `any characters` with `.+` to match any sequence of characters.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear in the question - my main issue is when I am matching say a symbol such as a `(`, `)` or `.` etc.
Thank you very much for the any characters though Barmar!

Comment: An advice, use scrowler pattern and replace `.+` with `[^']+` from m59 pattern.

Comment: Okay - What are the benefits to doing this? @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: @AlexHogg: this avoid many backtracking for the regex engine (because the `.` can match all characters including the `'`. In other words, it is faster.

Comment: @AlexHogg: I will post a description of the regex engine behaviour.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That would be great if you could - If I ever need to use regex again it would be extremely useful to understand how it works in depth.
On a side note - I've run into a problem - It's edited into the bottom of the question (if you could take a look I'd be extremely grateful).

Comment: @AlexHogg `$pattern = "arrname = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);";`

Comment: @Robin: you must add delimiters to the pattern: `$pattern = "~arrname = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);~";`

Comment: @AlexHogg: you can take a look now.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte @Robin
Thank you both very much for the help! I now have it all working as expected!
I unfortunately had to shoot off to a meeting yesterday, so have only just managed to look at the replies.
You can use any symbol to be a delimiter? (Or only the `~`)?

Comment: @AlexHogg: yes you have several possibilities, but try to not choose a character that have a special meaning in a regex or to choose a character that is always in use in your pattern (to avoid to escape it every five minutes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an aside comment, I will describe regex engine behaviour with two different patterns step by step. Keep in mind that this is only a short representation, in real life strings are processed character by character. The goal of this is to see the regex engine road.

**string:** `arr = array('cherry', 'apple');`

**pattern 1:** `arr = array\('(.+)', '(.+)'\);`

> `1  |` **arr = array('**cherry', 'apple');  `| arr = array\('` 
>   `2  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple');**`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>
> Since there is no `'` after the `;`, the regex engine must backtrack character by character to find a match. For each backtrack position the end of the pattern is tested. This is reason why I count each backtrack position as a step.
>
> `3  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple')**;`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>   `4  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple'**);`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>   `5  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple**');`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>
> The `'` is found, the regex engine stop to backtrack and continue
>
> `6  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple'**);`| arr = array\('(.+)',`
>
> There's no `,` after the `'` the RE restart backtracking to find another `'`
>
> `7  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'appl**e');`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>   `...`
>   `13 |` **arr = array('cherry',** 'apple');`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>
> another `'` is found
>
> `14 |` **arr = array('cherry', '**apple');`| arr = array\('(.+)'`
>
> but not followed by a `,` too
>
> `15 |` **arr = array('cherry',** 'apple');`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>   `16 |` **arr = array('cherry'**, 'apple');`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>   `17 |` **arr = array('cherry**', 'apple');`| arr = array\('(.+)`
>
> another `'` is found followed by a `, '`
>
> `18 |` **arr = array('cherry', '**apple');`| arr = array\('(.+)', '`
>   `19 |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple');**`| arr = array\('(.+)', '(.+)`
>
> There is no `'` after the `;`, ...
>
> `20 |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple')**;`| arr = array\('(.+)', '(.+)`
>   `21 |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple'**);`| arr = array\('(.+)', '(.+)`
>   `22 |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple**');`| arr = array\('(.+)', '(.+)`
>
> The `'` is found, followed by all the literals at the end of the pattern
>
> `23 |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple');**`| arr = array\('(.+)', '(.+)'\);`

**pattern 2:** `arr = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);`

> `1  |` **arr = array('**cherry', 'apple');  `| arr = array\('` 
>   `2  |` **arr = array('cherry**', 'apple'); `| arr = array\('([^']+)`
>
> Now the regex engine is forced to stop before the `'` since the character class contains all characters except the `'`
>
> `3  |` **arr = array('cherry', '**apple'); `| arr = array\('([^']+)', '` 
>   `4  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple**'); `| arr = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)`
>
> The RE stop before the `'` for the same reason
>
> `5  |` **arr = array('cherry', 'apple');** `| arr = array\('([^']+)', '([^']+)'\);`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how specific you need to be, this is a quick and clean way to go: `/'([^']+)'/`. That looks for anything between single quotes that isn't a single quote.

Comment: `/'([^']+)'/ seems more generic to me

Comment: @Robin oh yeah, that :) Updated. Thanks!!

Comment: Probably out of the scope for this question, `/'((?:\\'|.)+?)'/` if you wanna catch `'let\'s dance'`. Regex are awesome.

Comment: @Robin and you are apparently awesome with them!

Comment: @Robin: IMO, the best (most optimized) alternative is: `'(?s)((?>[^']++|\\{2}|\\.)+)(?-s)'`

Comment: I'll have to do some research on that, but this is starting to look pretty cool!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: would you mind giving me some pointer as to where to look for `(?s)`'s meaning? So far without it I don't really get the point of your atomic group: in the `'let\'s dance'` example, `[^']++` would match up to `let\ ` and since `'` matches neither `\\{2}` nor `\\.` the regex would stop there.

Comment: @Robin: `(?s)` is the only the inline version of the `\s` modifier (the dot can match newlines). Sorry, I have forgotten to put the backslash in the character class `[^'\\]++`. The use of the atomic group is essential if you want to avoid a catastrophic backtracking situation (example: a string that doesn't contain a closing quote)

Comment: @Robin: about inline modifiers: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: why do you need to turn off the `\s` modifier at the end? Yeah, I get the atomic group with the `[^'\\]++`. Didn't know about much of these properties, thanks for the readings!

Comment: @Robin: I turn it off only to return in the default mode (to not change the behaviour of possible other dots after). Obviously, if you need this mode after or if you don't have other dots after, it is not necessary.